# How to align text next to image?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have images flowing on both left to right and I want to have my text beside each images and I gave it something like this:

```
    <div>
<p style="float: left;"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" height="141px" width="212px" border="0px"></p>
<p>Etiam ac pellentesque lorem. Aliquam vel quam scelerisque, interdum eros id, ultricies est. Etiam in tristique urna. In a mi sit amet enim faucibus rhoncus. Etiam viverra nisl sed velit commodo rutrum. Nunc malesuada nulla sed nibh aliquet, nec fringilla lacus lacinia. Phasellus sed tristique odio.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="float: right;"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" height="141px" width="212px" border="0px"></p>
<p>Etiam ac pellentesque lorem. Aliquam vel quam scelerisque, interdum eros id, ultricies est. Etiam in tristique urna. In a mi sit amet enim faucibus rhoncus. Etiam viverra nisl sed velit commodo rutrum. Nunc malesuada nulla sed nibh aliquet, nec fringilla lacus lacinia. Phasellus sed tristique odio.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="float: left;"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" height="141px" width="212px" border="0px"></p>
<p>Etiam ac pellentesque lorem. Aliquam vel quam scelerisque, interdum eros id, ultricies est. Etiam in tristique urna. In a mi sit amet enim faucibus rhoncus. Etiam viverra nisl sed velit commodo rutrum. Nunc malesuada nulla sed nibh aliquet, nec fringilla lacus lacinia. Phasellus sed tristique odio.</p>
</div>
```

Here is an example of how I want it to replicate: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/banded.html

One of the problems I notice is that the height of the text seem to slightly off by a few pixels and how would I get it spot on to the height of 141px?

Comment: Paragraphs have built in margin/padding so you might want to see if zeroing those out solves your problem. If you could provide a JS Fiddle it would be easier to help you. I'm also unsure why you are putting the image in a `p` tag

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EmxCA/?

Comment: Ah, yes, something like that. I'm going to get rid of those tags and see how the results are.

Comment: Looks like that solves the problem. I forgot to set the style in the css, so the text was looking a little off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
div {
    clear:both;
}
p {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EmxCA/)**